# Curious class objects concatenate c++

Tags: c++, class, object, concatenation

```
#include <iostream>
#define CONCATENATE t; Box(); t 
#define END ;
using namespace std;

class Box
{
public:
      Box(){ }
      Box(string _txt){ }
      Box operator|(const Box& b)
      {  
         cout<<"hi from op |"<<endl;
         Box box;
         return box;
      }
      void operator+()
      {  

      }
public:
      string str;
};

int main( )
{
    Box t;
    Box tt;

   CONCATENATE //this works 
   CONCATENATE  CONCATENATE //this doesn't work because cant understand tt object
   END
}
```

if i give CONCATENATE CONCATENATE compilers says that semicolon missing thats correct but compiler should understand t; Box(); tt; Box(); t because during the phases of analysis removes the spaces.

if i write CONCATENATE END compiler executes that and is correct
t; Box(); t;
if i write CONCATENATE CONCATENATE END compiler executes that and is not correct
t; Box(); t t; Box(); t; because understands that semicolon missing but in this case i want the compiler to understand that should execute the object tt and to ignore the space.

How i can do that guys?

- **update**

  preprocessor concatenates the strings to tt; object?

  ```
  int main( ){
      Box t;
      Box tt;

      //this work (is such 2 times CONCATENATE macro)
      t; Box(); tt; Box(); t END
      //this doesnt work
      CONCATENATE CONCATENATE END

  }
  ```

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve here? [This is almost certainly the wrong way to do it.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/242291)

Comment: check my update.thanks!

Comment: @jay_gr13 Your update still doesn't well explain you use case for this construct. Makes no sense for me.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ thanks for your reply,please check again my update is more clear!

Comment: @jay_gr13 No your update doesn't really clarify anything about your use case. The output of your macros (even if they would work as you seem to intend to) looks pretty useless.

Answer (score 1):

As for your *"updates"*:

> preprocessor concatenates the strings to tt; object?

No, the preprocessor doesn't concatenate anything, unless you instruct it with the [`##` string concatenation preprocessing operation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html). I does simply text replacement, so let's have a lookup to your replacements from the preprocessor:

```
//this work (is such 2 times CONCATENATE macro)
t; Box(); tt; Box(); t END
//this doesnt work
CONCATENATE CONCATENATE END
```

will be expanded to

```
//this work (is such 2 times CONCATENATE macro)
t; Box(); tt; Box(); t ;
//this doesnt work
t; Box(); t t; Box(); t ;
```

`t t;` isn't recognized as valid syntax. Your assumption it will be concatenated to `tt` is wrong.

Comment: You have catch what i want.. is possible to make something to fix it?

Comment: @jay_gr13 I'm afraid no, unless you introduce another macro taking two parameters and use the [`##` concatenation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html) operator as mentioned.